# OpenOLAT 10.0.9 not responding

Tags: tomcat7, catalina

I've set up OpenOLAT with following installation guide: http://www.openolat.com/fileadmin/adminwiki/QW5vdGhlcl9JbnN0YWxsYXRpb25fR3VpZGU=.html

I am able to view the Tomcat website at http://example.com:8080/, but I am not able to view the OpenOLAT page at http://example.com:8088/.

But why? The catalina.out says, that everthing was initialized correct and no error was displayed.

```
    $ netstat -tulpen | grep 80
    tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       12885       6766/java
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       12884       6766/java
    tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1001       12892       6766/java
```

I just can not find the following line in the catalina.out:

```
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/openolat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the problems? Try it with OpenOLAT 10.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Check the file and permission of server.xml under CATALINA_HOME